# C# TrimEnd trimming too many chars

Tags: c#

I'm seeing odd results when using string.TrimEnd() method

```
var s = "FDLBicester.freshviprint01";
var x = s.TrimEnd("freshviprint01".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Produces

`FDLBicester.`

However, slightly changing the TrimEnd to include the `.` as well:

```
var s = "FDLBicester.freshviprint01";
var x = s.TrimEnd(".freshviprint01".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Produces

`FDLBic`

????

Why am I losing `ester` by also trimming the `.`?

Comment: Read here - Remarks 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It works as spected acording to the doc, check the link provided by @pitersmx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TrimEnd()` will trim *all* the characters passed to it.

When you don't pass the `.` the trimming stops there, since the `.` isn't in the list of chars to trim.

When you *do* pass the `.`, then it *is* in the list of chars to trim - and so are several other characters before it (namely, `e`, `s`, `t` and `r`), which therefore also get trimmed.

Comment: In other words `"aaabbbb.b".TrimEnd(".b".ToCharArray())` will result in `aaa` because `b` is cointained in `.b`. You should use Substring instead TrimEnd

Answer (score 2):

when you put

```
  var x = s.TrimEnd(".freshviprint01".ToCharArray());
```

you actually want to remove *all* the *trailing characters* from `{'.', '0', '1', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'p', 'r', 'r', 's', 't', 'v'}` set (`c` i s the *first* character that's *not* in the set):

```
  "FDLBicester.freshviprint01" -> "FDLBic"
```

please, notice that all the characters in the `icester` are *presented* in the set and that's why are *trimmed out*. You, probably, want to cut off some suffix, like this:

```
  var s = "FDLBicester.freshviprint01";
  var suffix = ".freshviprint01";

  var x = s.EndsWith(suffix) 
    ? s.Substring(0, s.Length - suffix.Length) 
    : s;
```

Answer (score 1):

`TrimEnd` trimms every character from the end that is part of the passed trim array, and repeats this until the last character of the string is not part of the array.

```
var s = "FDLBicester.freshviprint01";
var x = s.TrimEnd(".freshviprint01".ToCharArray());
```

The chars in `cester.freshviprint01` are all part of the trim array, that's why they get removed. It does not matter in which order they are passed.

```
var x = s.TrimEnd(".01efihnprstv".ToCharArray());
```

would have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The `TrimEnd` function removes any of those `char`s from the end of the string. It doesn't match the full string.

Try this instead:

```
var s = "FDLBicester.freshviprint01";
var t = ".freshviprint01";

var x =
    s.Length > t.Length && s.Substring(s.Length - t.Length) == t
        ? s.Substring(0, s.Length - t.Length) 
        : s;

Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Or even this:

```
var x = s.Split(new [] { t }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```